# Get outside wireframe

Tags: edges, wireframe

I am a begginer and have to make something like that:
[image]

With plane geometry I can easily make, but with curves the triangulation gets in the way... 
[image]

How to make a wireframe only for external edges, anyone can help??
If I just delete the undesirable faces my external ones gets all bored.

I can get a mesh with only the edges if it helps, but I need to be able to assing materials to edges.

[image]

English ins't my language, sorry!

EDIT 1 ----

With @Martin Z I get this:

[image]

And that is great! But I need to close this gaps, any ideia?

EDIT 2 ----

With @Martin Z and @Carlo i successfully make this geometry! Thanks guys!
But with another geometry with a hole in it I can't...
My mesh come like this (left) and a apply the decimate modifi (right):

[image]

If I delete the edeges in blue (the left blue ones, with shouldn't exist), I end with holes in my mesh (blue right):

[image]

Any way to get the holes out? If I make one by one it could get much time, I have 62 geometry like this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The definition of "external" is in this case dependent from the point of view. Howare you planning to address that?

Comment: You could duplicate the desired edges and separate into a separate mesh and then add a Skin modifier - similar to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/65603/29586

Comment: @Carlo External is the edges that don't make a face, in a the second image internal edges makes te cylinder

Comment: @RichSedman the skin modifier make the intersections between edger "rounded" some way to make it 90º?

Comment: @LucasLauri I'm afraid there isn't a way to do that with Skin - unfortunately there isn't much control over how the edges join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Wireframe or Skin modifiers(note that you can adjust the radius per vertex in the n panel while in edit mode for skin modifier or with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>).

With Wireframe modifier you'll have to keep an eye on your mesh edges. Use N-gons wisely in order to pass the operator just the edges you need. For the provided example, a solution could be something like:

[image]

As you see the trick is to not build a complete mesh, but just the faces that hold the right edges. You'll also be able to assign different materials to the edges with vertex paint without having to apply the modifier.

You can also select only edges you want, invert selection with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, delete everything else, select all and delete only faces (<kbd>x</kbd> menu) and then you are left with edges only. Then from object mode you can convert them to curves(<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) and then you can add thickness to them:

[image]

If you wish once you are happy with them you may convert them back to polygons with the same shortcut <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Comment: Hey @Martin Z thas works great! But my mesh get little gaps that I need to fill, any idea? Maybe make this mesh solid? Put an image in the first post. Thank you!

Comment: can I make a wireframe with selected edge? This could be an option two

Comment: No, not really. There are no native operators in Blender that would do so. Its not complicated to make one with Python, however that does not seem like a very useful function to me as it is quite easy to just duplicate selected edges and separate them and then convert them to a curve. Yes it's more work then just click a shortcut with selected edges, but this is not something a modeller would do often.  If you have a good reason for needing it, I can write the script for you. I cannot think of any good reasons one would want such a function though.

Comment: With this model I get what I need with your help and what Carlo edit in yours post. But with another geometry (with has a hole) I can't make a ngon from the meshs... My good reason is make 62 geometry like this :( With isn't all bad if a dont have to adjust every faces intersection, but like this is terrible. I will edit the original post with new geometry. Thank you very much Martin! could help me a little more?

Comment: @Carlo with your edit I successffuly make this geometry, but in a geometry withi a hole in it I can't make a ngon, did you have any another idea? I will update the original post with this new problem..

Comment: You do not need o have all the geometry connected. You can have floating unconnected overlapping faces instead of holes. If you make sure you have Boundary option ticked in the Wireframe modifier it works fine.

Comment: Ngons doesn't currently support holes. I agree with @MartinZ that for the presented purpose, unconnected geometry should works. You don't have to think about "modeling an object", you should focus on building the support geometry for your wires.

Comment: Yep! That works great! Thanks a lot guys! You two really had helped me